# ViewBinding does not work proprely with FragmenContainerView

Tags: xml, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, android-viewbinding

Im trying to use a **navigation** with **FragmentContainerView** inside a MainActivity xml.. But when I try to use the **binding**  features into MainActivity it **returns an error**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.github.derleymad.luixo/com.github.derleymad.luixo.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11 in com.github.derleymad.luixo:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #11 in com.github.derleymad.luixo:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
```

But when I use :`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` instead of the `ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)` it works! why???

**here's my MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.github.derleymad.luixo

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import com.github.derleymad.luixo.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var viewModel : MainViewModel
    private lateinit var binding : ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
//        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)  //ERROR HERE
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) //  WORK FINE WITH THIS WAY
//        setContentView(binding.root) // ERROR HERE
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[MainViewModel::class.java]
        viewModel.fetchCoins()
    }
}
```

**The MainActivity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/base_main_navigation"
/> //THIS IS THE LINE 11
```

**The base_main_navigation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/base_main_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:name="com.github.derleymad.luixo.ui.main.MainFragment"
        android:label="fragment_main"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" >
    </fragment>

</navigation>
```

**The MainFragment.xml (hostfragment)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view_perfil_image"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="24dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/perfil_img"
            android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nome_usuario"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Seja bem vindo ..."
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/card_view_perfil_image"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/card_view_perfil_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/card_view_perfil_image" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/main_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/gray_ligt"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/card_view_perfil_image">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <include
                android:id="@+id/included"
                layout="@layout/saldo_generic"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_go"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_forward_24"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/main_card"
        app:tabBackground="@color/white"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicator="@drawable/tab_indicator"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/black"
        app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="false"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
        app:tabInlineLabel="true"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/black"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/CustomTabStyle"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/gray" />

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tab_layout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```